# Samsung TV HDMI connection no audio

Tags: hdmi, tv

The Samsung TV model number is: LN32A450C1D

When I connect my PC to the TV, there is video output but no audio output. It is only HDMI connections that do not have audio output. I have connected my Wii via component cables and the audio works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to check what Windows (sometimes the graphic card app) has set for the default sound output device.

On Windows, try this:

1. Right-click the Speaker icon on the system tray, and choose **Playback Devices**
2. Click on the appropriate device, and click **Set Default**
3. Click **OK**

Same thing applies if you're using a discrete graphics card. You'll need to change the sound output to the appropriate device, in which case, the TV.